# capture the exception from a test in conftest

Tags: python, pytest

I capture the test results from all my tests and write them to a html file in my conftest.py. I am able to get the test_name, class_name, module_name and the result of the test passed/failed in my conftest.py. I would also like to capture the exception that a given test failed on.

In this example, test2 and test3 would fail and i would like to capture the stacktrace of the exception in my conftest file.

test.py

```
def test1():
    assert 1 == 1

def test2():
    assert 1 == 2

def test3():
    pytest.fail('abc')
```

conftest.py

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    if rep.when == 'call':
        setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def runtime_report(request):
    yield
    test_name = request.node.name
    class_name = ''
    module_name = ''
    test_result = ''
    parent_type_name = type(request.node.parent).__name__
    if parent_type_name == 'Module':
        class_name = None
        module_name = request.node.parent.name
    elif parent_type_name == 'Instance':
        class_name = request.node.parent.parent.name
        module_name = request.node.parent.parent.parent.name
    else:
        pytest.fail('Unknown parent %s for node %s' % (
            request.node.parent.name,
            request.node.name
        ))
    # And then Logic for writing the results to html file below.
```